# Kindly anyone tell me how to make anything slider in HTML websites?

Tags: slider, anythingslider

Kindly Let us know i have nivo slider in my websites now want to go for a anything slider to create and to add a videos kindly pls help me regarding this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use the html version of it available at https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider, which also has documentation to tell you how to use it.